# Android SQLite database upgrade, get previous version

Tags: android, database, sqlite, upgrade

Is there a way, when there is a database upgrade with onUpgrade() method, to get the previous database?.

I mean, if current database version in 2 and I change it to 3, onUpgrade method is called, but after that is there a way to get the database corresponding to version 2 ?

Comment: Sounds as though you would want to handle that yourself.  You could be sure to store a slightly different database within the onUpgrade() that could be referenced later.  Otherwise, you would be overwriting your old database usually and it wouldn't be reversible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot *get* the previous version, because now it is upgraded to version 3.

What you can do, is downgrade the database to the previous version with [`onDowngrade`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onDowngrade%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20int,%20int%29) when you deliver a new app with database version 2. Although, this is only available from API level 11.

Answer (score 7):

No, there isn't. When you upgrade your database, the older version is overwritten.

You could try making a backup copy by copying the file from the internal storage's `databases` folder to your normal internal storage or the external storage, and then restoring it if you have to.